# python: pass data to class constructor

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an Account class that has 3 data fields (id, balance, annual interest rate).  Everything is working well if I just print out what the balance is or call some functions to get the monthly interest, etc...
but I need to show the results of doing a deposit and withdrawal as well and that's where I'm stuck, I'm guessing I have to do something like this

```
ending_balance = account.withdraw(2500) + account.deposit(3000)
```

but I'm not sure how to the take that ending balance and pass it to the Account constructor so that the interest rates will adjust according to the new balance.

```
class Account:

    def __init__(self, id, balance, annual_interest_rate):
        self.__id = id
        self.__balance = balance
        self.__annual_interest_rate = annual_interest_rate



    def withdraw(self, withdrawal):
        return float(self.get_balance() - withdrawal)

    def deposit(self, deposit):
        return float(self.get_balance() + deposit)


def main():

    account = Account(1122, 20000, 4.5)
    ending_balance = account.withdraw(2500) + account.deposit(3000)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Instead of `return`ing the values, update the `self.__balance` in withdraw and deposit methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your `withdraw` and `deposit` have to update the actual field, to force this use your `self.set_balance` or just directly `self.__balance = newbalance` :

```
def withdraw(self, withdrawal):
    self.set_balance(self.get_balance() - withdrawal)
    return float(self.get_balance() - withdrawal)

def deposit(self, deposit):
    self.set_balance(self.get_balance() + deposit)
    return float(self.get_balance() + deposit)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is Regarding the logic in the main function.

```
    account = Account(1122, 20000, 4.5)
    ending_balance = account.withdraw(2500) + account.deposit(3000)
```

The above line doesn't provide the ending balance.

Do these changes,

```
def withdraw(self, withdrawal):
    self.__balance = self.get_balance() - withdrawal
    return float(self.__balance)

def deposit(self, deposit):
    self.__balance = self.get_balance() - deposit
    return float(self.__balance)
```

and calling it in the main as,

```
 account.withdraw(2500)
 ending_balance = account.deposit(3000)
```

would provide the right ending balance.